# Is there a replacement for this double math

Tags: java

Is there a Java operator that would create a value equal to count but in fewer lines?

```
    double theta = //Some value;
    int count = 0;
    while (theta > 0) {
        theta -= pi * (1.0 / 8.0);
        count += 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've just implemented division by repeated subtraction.

So, if you had actual real numbers in Java, you could do ...

```
int result = (int) (theta / (Math.PI / 8)) + 1;
```

... to get the same result. However due to repeated rounding errors in your code, that has many more steps than a simple division, the answers will diverge a bit. The results will be the same for thetas up to around 55 million.

The rounding errors are there because `float` and `double` are not accurate representations of real numbers.

See also: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: This would give a different output if `theta = Math.PI / 8`

Comment: @Eran Yours gives a different output if `theta == Math.PI * 8` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `theta > 0`, something like this should work:

```
int count = (int)Math.ceil (theta/(Math.PI * (1.0 / 8.0)));
```

or

```
int count = (int)Math.ceil (theta*8/Math.PI);
```

Comment: The code posted by the OP does neither exactly `Math.ceil` nor `+ 1`, there are edge cases for both (take theta is `Math.PI / 8` or `Math.PI * 8`)

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `Math.ceil( theta/(pi * (1.0 / 8.0)))`?